# How to set up a Zephyr Project App in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote, zephyr-rtos

I am trying to use VSC to develop and debug embedded C applications with Zephyr OS. Is this possible? Are there instructions to set this up? Is there a zephyr setup extension? The Zephyr documentation discusses how to debug apps on eclipse, and there is an eclipse/zephyr plug-in, but I'd prefer to use VSC if possible.

Since Zephyr utilizes CMake, I thought I follow the VSC CMake project tutorial. When it asks to select a kit, there was nothing appropriate for zephyr, so I left it with no active kit selected. With this setting, I am actually able to get a successful build for the blinky example but cannot debug the project. The error I get is:

> ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command
> "-exec-run". Don't know how to run.  Try "help target". The program
> '/home/mustafa/Code/Sycamore/hello_world/build/zephyr/zephyr.elf' has
> exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).

If anyone has any input on how to address this error or instructions on setting up a zephyr project in VSC, that would be great. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Only few steps enough:

1. Add necessary folders to workspace like:

> ```
> "folders": [
>   {
>       "path": ".",
>       "name": "app"
>   },
>   {
>       "path": "..\\zephyr",
>       "name": "zephyr"
>   },
>   {
>       "path": "..\\mcuboot"
>   },
>   {
>       "path": "..\\modules\\hal\\stm32"
>   }
> ]
> ```

2. Install [Cortex-Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marus25.cortex-debug) extension
3. Setup debug session in file .vscode/launch.json:

   ```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "App",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "executable": "./app/build/zephyr/zephyr.elf",
        "request": "attach",
        "type": "cortex-debug",
        "serverpath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServerCL.exe",
        "servertype": "jlink",
        "device": "stm32f412RE",
        "interface": "swd",
        "svdFile": "./STM32F412.svd"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bootloader",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "executable": "./boot/build/zephyr/boot.elf",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "cortex-debug",
        "serverpath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServerCL.exe",
        "servertype": "jlink",
        "device": "stm32f412RE",
        "interface": "swd",
        "runToMain": true,
        "svdFile": "./STM32F412.svd"
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Eugene for sharing the info above. Wasn't really clear in which file I am supposed to add the "folders" directive above but I went ahead and I added the zephyr and module directories from the zephyr repo to my workspace. Not sure if this is the same.

Comment: I downloaded the cortex-debug extension and created the following launch.json:

Comment: {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "executable": "./build/zephyr/zephyr.elf",
            "name": "Test",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "servertype": "jlink",
            "device": "nRF52833_xxAA",
            "serverpath": "/usr/bin/JLinkGDBServerCLExe",
            "interface": "swd"
        }

    ]
}

Comment: But I got an error saying "undefined GDB executable "arm-none-eabi-gdb" was not found. Please configure "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath" or "cortex-debug.gdbPath" correctly."

Comment: Any idea how to address this error? Please keep in mind that I have the C/C++ extension installed with gdb debugging.

Comment: Zephyr contains a lot of unnecessary (in my project) modules, so it's easier to import only useful folders to increase search speed.
My .vscode/settings.json file contains only one line: 

```
{                                                                                                                                                                 "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNUARM"                                                                                          }  
```